# rotate a polygon based on its centre with snap

Tags: ios, algorithm, cocoa, coordinates, polygon

I'm developing a 2D application on iOS, what I need to do is to rotate a polygon based on its centre, and also achieve snap. Now I'm able to correctly rotate it, but I've no idea about how to achieve snap (when there are any side of the polygon is very close to be horizontal or vertical, automatically make it horizontal or vertical). Here is my current code, I'm using a slider to rotate this polygon

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {

    // get rotateAngle
    double rotateAngle = sender.value;

    // if choosing any room, rotate it
    if (choosedRoomAtIndex>0){

        // get the room
        NSMutableArray *corners = rooms[choosedRoomAtIndex-1];

        // calculate center point
        double centerX;
        double centerY;
        for (NSValue *pointValue in corners){
            CGPoint cornerPoint = [pointValue CGPointValue];
            centerX += cornerPoint.x;
            centerY += cornerPoint.y;
        }
        CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(centerX/corners.count, centerY/corners.count);

        // calculate snap angle
        **How To Calculate the angles that make any side horizontal or vertical?**

        // rotate all the corner point based on the rotate angle
        for (int j=0; j<corners.count; j++) {

            // get current point
            CGPoint cornerPoint = [corners[j] CGPointValue];

            // if very close to horizontal or vertical, snap it
            if (fabs(rotateAngle-/*any snap angle*/)<rotateThreshold){
                rotateAngle = /*this snap angle*/;
                NSLog(@"here");
            }

            // perform the rotate
            double s = sin(rotateAngle-lastRotatedAngle);
            double c = cos(rotateAngle-lastRotatedAngle);
            double newX = (cornerPoint.x-centerPoint.x)*c - (cornerPoint.y-centerPoint.y)*s + centerPoint.x;
            double newY = (cornerPoint.x-centerPoint.x)*s + (cornerPoint.y-centerPoint.y)*c + centerPoint.y;
            CGPoint movedPoint = CGPointMake(newX,newY);
            [corners replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:movedPoint]];

        }
        [rooms replaceObjectAtIndex:choosedRoomAtIndex-1 withObject:corners];
        lastRotatedAngle = rotateAngle;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }

}
```

Is there anyone could help me about this algorithm? Any posts will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the edges of your polygon run between consecutive corners (with the last edge wrapping round from the last corner to the first).  If that's the case, the angle for any corner to the next is given by

tan(angle) = ((corners[i+1].y - corners[i].y)/(corners[i+1].x - corners[i].x)

Here angle is the angle below the x-axis (clockwise).  So to snap this back to horizontal, you would need to rotate by -angle.  I would also calculate the angle to rotate to the vertical (swap x and y in the above equation), and pick the smaller of the two.  You will need to watch out for the divide by zero if two corners are already horizontally or vertically aligned (in which case, no need to snap?).  You may need to watch out for cases where the "next" corner is to the left, or above, the current corner, though in practice I think this will not matter since you presumably want to pick the smallest snap angle.

I would loop through all corners and find the horizontal and vertical snap angle for each, and then use the smallest of all those angles.  Note the formula above is maths, not code - you need to do the CGPointValue method to extract from the NSValues, for example.  And you will need to use atan to get the angle from the above formula.